# Datasheet of arduino power jack

Tags: power, shields, components

Can we find out about the parts that the arduino uses?

I want to make a shield, and i bought the same power jacks.

And i thought that there would be two pins, one for power, one for GND.
However, it has three pins.

The supplier did not have a datasheet, and right now i do not have a continuity beeper either, so could i see its datasheet somewhere, or does anyone know why it has three pins?

Comment: The third pin is connected to the sleeve pin, if there is no jack plugged in. It disconnects when a jack is plugged in. You can use it to detect if a jack is plugged in. You can even use it have you project run on batteries, and automatically switch if a power-jack is plugged in. Though in almost all cases you leave it disconnected, or connect it to the sleeve pin. PS this third pin also makes it so the plug is more solidly connected to the PCB.

Comment: @Gerben Thank you! But which is the center pin, and which is the third pin?
Plus, i suppose that the polarity of these two pins is GND right? I mean the extra pin (whatever it is), is not connected to the center of the power connector (the power), but to the side (the GND). Am i correct?

Comment: @timemage. Hello. What do you mean?

Comment: Just me venting.  I had written an answer.  It's gone now.  I find it extremely frustrating that no one pays attention to the thing that is literally written right on the box that I am typing into now, which says "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. **Avoid answering questions in comments.**"

Comment: @timemage Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: Partly out of frustration, partly out of the experience that when a comment contains an answer, the actual answers go ignored.  With the answer gone, I can make a point about this without driving traffic to the answer I gave.

Comment: @timemage I understand your frustation. Answer it again, if you'd like and i will upvote and mark as accepted.

Comment: Credit for it is something I gave up to avoid a conflict of interest when venting about it.  If you just want to view it for yourself, it'll be at https://timemage.wereclam.net/tmp/da.png for a few minutes.  It's nothing to write home about, but it is(was) an *answer*.  If you like it, vote up jwh20's answer if you haven't already.

Comment: @timemage I did upvote his answer. But almost everything i wanted is contained in your answer. So please, answer again, don't type anything, just add the image if you want (if you are bored). Come on you deserve it! Plus i got just one question about this. I will ask you in the comments ;)

Comment: @Gerben "This one on connected the the sleeve pin, if there is no jack inserted (so yes, you were correct). " Sorry i didn't get this, you have a typo.

Comment: The center pin is connected to the back. The sleeve in on the bottom. The switched contact is the one on the side. This one is connected the the sleeve pin, if there is no jack inserted (so yes, you were correct). In most power jacks the sleeve in ground, but this isn't always the case. **(corrected misspellings)**

Answer (score 1):

This is an image from a typical power jack:

[image: From here https://www.we-online.de/katalog/datasheet/6941xx301002.pdf]

The specific ones you bought may differ.  The vendor should be able to supply you with a manufacturer and P/N or an actual data sheet.

Image copied from: https://www.we-online.de/katalog/datasheet/6941xx301002.pdf